# What happened to the ros-fuerte-roslisp-* debs?

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What happened to the `ros-fuerte-roslisp-common` and `ros-fuerte-roslisp-support` debian packages? Right now (2013-04-08) the Ubuntu 11.10 Debian repo seems to contain roslisp for electric, groovy and unstable, but not fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60235/what-happened-to-the-ros-fuerte-roslisp-*-debs?/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-08**:
Yup, looks like it, thanks for the link. Since the packages are not marked as "intentionally missing", I'm still hoping they will be back soon. This recent round of updates probably shouldn't have been pushed to the repo...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-09**:
Hopefully so. The Hudson status page shows **devel** copies building cleanly on Fuerte. You might open a ticket, in case the maintainers have not noticed the problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the builds are failing on all the Fuerte platforms: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1